# Combining strings without using plus '+'

Tags: java, string, java-8

I am writing unit tests now and I need to create a specific string.

I have now defined something like this:

```
private final String at = "@:";
private String error, effect, one, two, three, four;
```

in setUp (@Before):

```
    error = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic (3);
    one = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic (6);
    two = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic (8);
    three = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic (2);
    four = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic (6);
    effect = (error + at + one + at + two + at + three + at + four);
```

The combination of the strings with the pluses looks terribly ugly and amateurish. Is it possible to do it somehow more efficiently using anything else? For example pattern? I dont know. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Use a StringBuilder

Comment: Note that non-determinism in tests is generally undesirable. As in, do you *really* want a different string each time, or would a randomly-generated-but-fixed string suffice?

Comment: @AndyTurner, it depends on what kind of test you are making. If you are fuzzing, it seems very appropriate.

Comment: @RobAu even if you are fuzzing, determinism is preferable: generate a large number of inputs deterministically, and you can actually debug a problem it finds; generate them non-deterministically, and you're just playing computational whack-a-mole.

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but I thought the goal of fuzzing was to provide 'unexpected, random' data. If it is deterministic, you might never encounter some cases that you might hit randomly.

Comment: As @RobAu says, as long as the random elements are output in the event of failure, it's then trivial to introduce a unit test to cover that failure case.

Comment: This not ugly neither amateurish, eventually inefficient, to optimize allocations use `StringBuilder`

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès: there’s not even any benefit from manual `StringBuilder` use here. The concatenation using `+` is fine as is. Starting with Java 9, it might even outperform all alternatives, including manual `StringBuilder` use…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simplicity, you can also do:

```
String.join(at, error,one, two, three, four);
```

Comment: Where the first argument is a delimiter.

Comment: exactly, sorry I omitted that.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the java built-in [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(error);
sb.append(at);
sb.append(one);
...
effect = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

If the "@:" is a consistent separator, and you're using Java 8+, you might find that [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) is your friend. This would look something like:

```
effect = String.join("@:", error, one, two, three, four);
```

Guessing a little bit from your variable names, but as a little background and just in case it's helpful, if you want/need to use a Stream you can also use [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--), which could look something like:

```
List<String> stringParts = ...
stringParts.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.joining("@:"));
```

This will join everything in the list with "@:" as a delimiter. You can also add a constant prefix and/or suffix which might be relevant for your `error` variable, like:

```
String error = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(3);
List<String> stringParts = ...
stringParts.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.joining("@:", error, ""));
```

Comment: Even with a “dynamic number of Strings”, i.e. `List<String> stringParts`, you can still use `effect = String.join("@:", stringParts);`

Comment: @Holger - good point, thank you I've edited to correct that oversight.